# Is ftruncate() asynchronous?

Tags: c++, file, file-io, atomic, acid

I am attempting to write a class in C++ that provides a means of atomically appending to a file, even for the case of power failure mid write.

First, I write my current file position (a 64 bit offset from the beginning of the file, in bytes) to a separate journal file. Then, I write the requested data to the end of the data file. Finally, I call `ftruncate()` (setting the truncated size to 0) on the journal file.

The main idea is that if this class is ever asked to open a file that has a non empty journal file, then you know a write was interrupted and you can read the position of the last write from the journal file and `fseek()` to that spot. You lose the last partial write, but the file should not be corrupted.

Unfortunately, it seems like `ftruncate()` is asynchronous. In practice, even if I call `fflush()` and `fsync()` after `ftruncate()` I see the journal grow to up to hundreds of bytes while doing lots of writes. It always ultimately ends up at 0, but I expected to see it at either size 0 or size 8 at all times.

Is it possible to make `ftruncate()` completely synchronous? Or is there a better way to use the journal?

Comment: What if power fails again while you're recovering the journal?

Comment: "is there a better way to use the journal?" - depends on your recovery requirements.  Writing some "next-block-should-be-N-bytes" message into your data file would avoid the need for the separate journal (and head repositioning that's slow on magnetic HDDs), providing that in a recovery situation you've either time to rescan the file from the start - jumping along the blocks, or can distinguish such next-block-N-byte content from other content when scanning backwards from the end of the file.  Memory mapping is probably a little more elegant for the journal too.

Comment: @Kerrek - Journal recovery essentially consists of placing the write position such that the last partial write is overwritten. As such, it doesn't require any writes to the data file. If the power fails during journal recovery, that's fine... you'll just recover the journal the next time you start up.

Comment: This doesn't seem like it has much (if anything) to do with C++.  This seems entirely like an OS/FS issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ftruncate()` does not change your file descriptor's write offset in the file.  If you are leaving the file open and writing the next length after calling `ftruncate()`, then what's happening is the file's offset is still increasing.  When you write, it resets the length of the file to be at the offset and then writes your bytes there.

Probably what you want to do is call `lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET)` after you call `ftruncate()` so that the next write to the file will take place at the beginning of the file.

Comment: Or use `pwrite(fd, &data, sizeof(data), 0)` instead of `write` to write at offset=0 in the journal file.  ([Linux man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pread.2.html) / [POSIX man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/write.3p.html)). It doesn't care about or update the file position for `fd`, so you don't have to make `lseek` system calls, just `fdatasync` and `ftruncate`.  AFAIK there's no C stdio equivalent, but we don't want C stdio for the journal.